# PyQt: custom widget appearing along with main window

Tags: python, window, pyqt, show

I have created a main GUI and coded in a single file called one.py. There is a need to call a custom GUI/widget in from the main script. The second custom GUI/widget is created with qt designer and the working script is called second.py.

It works fine when I execute second.py. The second GUI must be triggered when a variable from one.py changes. The GUI pops up fine as expected when variable is change in one.py. However, along with the second GUI, the next widget from one.py also shows as well. The example script of one.py looks like this:

```
if variable:
    self.child_win = PersistenceGui(self)
    self.child_win.show()

    QtGui.QMessageBox.information("Some info to the users.")
```

In the above case, the child window and info box are shown together. But I want Info box to be shown only after closing the child window/GUI box. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `PersistenceGui` a subclass of `QDialog`, and then show it like this:

```
    self.child_win.exec_()
```

This will block until the user closes the dialog, and then the message-box will be shown.

**EDIT**:

If you want to know if the user cancelled the dialog, then try this:

```
    if self.child_win.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information("Some info to the users.")
    else:
        # ask if user wants to close main window, or whatever...
```

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks.

Comment: There is an another problem popping up. I have an "closeEvent" function for close (X icon of the GUI) to ask users to quit the main window. However, after the `self.child_win.exec_()` executed, "closeEvent" is triggered asking if user want to quit the main window. I am not sure how the "closeEvent" is have connection with the custom widget code.

Comment: @sundar_ima. I assume the `closeEvent` is in the dialog. If so, see my updated answer for an alternative way of handling this.

Comment: No. The problem still persist. I think `QtGui.qApp.closeAllWindows()` present in the custom widget GUI is conflicting with the `closeEvent` function present in the main script. Is it possible to close the custom GUI without triggering `QtGui.qApp.closeAllWindows()` in the second GUI script?

Comment: Solved the issue by replacing `QtGui.qApp.closeAllWindows()` with `self.close()` in the second GUI script which does not trigger the `closeEvent`.